# Swift - Best Practices for Staging Value Changes

Tags: ios, swift

I can't figure out how to phrase this into a concise enough question for google. I'm trying to figure out the best way to stage value changes within a certain view that the user will make changes in and be able to save or discard them.

For example, here is a very simplified scenario:

```
class ClassToSave {
   var quantity = 0
}
```

Now, say I have a view where the user can edit this quantity. I'm trying to figure out the best way to track these changes for when the user saves so I can see that the old quantity was this and the new quantity is that.

One idea was to duplicate the object, which sucks keeping up with since the copy function has to be populated with all of the variables within the class and I'll certainly forget any new variables that are added.

Another was to have an element of that class type within the class called pendingChanges or something:

```
class ClassToSave {
   var quantity = 0
   var pendingChanges = ClassToSave()
}
```

But, this is pretty much the same issue as the copy function, upkeep. The values in the pending class need to be set at some point. It definitely makes more sense in my head though than using the copy function.

Another was to have a dedicated class for tracking the changes because I don't need to track every single variable in the class. It's usually just a handful.

The last and sloppiest way I can think of is to just have variables within the view controller that store the pending values.

I'm sure there is a standard for this kind of thing. I just don't know it and can't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple question with a very simple answer. Use structs instead of classes, they are made for exactly this situation:

```
struct ClassToSave: Equatable {
  var quantity = 0    
}

// this is your original data
var original = ClassToSave(quantity: 1)

// this is a copy, with changes
var current = original
current.quantity = 10

// you can compare them
let hasChanges = (original != current)
```

Comment: Not that I think this is bad - but they said they didn't want to use variables to store the pending changes.

Comment: @Jay This is not the same. You don't need a separate variable for every property.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you for the suggestion. I do rely on references for a good amount of things. That does include the classes I am trying to stage these changes for. I could obviously refactor to not rely on references, but that wouldn't be preferable since this task is a small part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Codable` and convert your object into a `Dictionary` which you could use to save your original values.  Then use that dictionary and compare it against a dictionary created when you need to check for changes.  Not a perfect solution and surely has some limitations but could be viable depending on your usage.

```
class MyObject: NSObject, Codable {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var height: Double?
    var occupation: String?
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == AnyHashable {
    func editedKeys(_ obj: Encodable) -> [String]? {
        let dict = obj.dictionary
        var changes = [String]()
        for key in self.keys {
            if let value = self[key], let newValue = dict[key], value != newValue {
                changes.append(key)
            } else if let _ = self[key], dict[key] == nil {
                changes.append(key)
            } else if let _ = dict[key], self[key] == nil {
                changes.append(key)
            }
        }
        return changes.count > 0 ? changes : nil
    }
}

struct JSON {
    static let encoder = JSONEncoder()
}
extension Encodable {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        return dictionary[key]
    }
    var dictionary: [String: AnyHashable] {
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSON.encoder.encode(self))) as! [String: AnyHashable]
    }
}
```

Useage:

```
let person = MyObject()
person.name = "Jim"
person.age = 25
person.height = 69
person.occupation = "Accountant"

let oldValues = person.dictionary

person.age = 26
person.height = 70
person.occupation = nil

if let editedKeys = oldValues.editedKeys(person) {
    print(editedKeys)
    let newValues = person.dictionary
    for key in editedKeys {
        if let oldValue = oldValues[key], let newValue = newValues[key] {
            print("\(key) \(oldValue) -> \(newValue)")
        } else if self[key] != nil, dict[key] == nil {
            changes.append(key)
        } else if dict[key] != nil, self[key] == nil {
            changes.append(key)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
changes: ["height", "age", "occupation"] 

height 69 -> 70  
age 25 -> 26  
occupation Accountant -> nil
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I like the idea of storing the object as a Dictionary.